# How to access Kendo Datepicker's raw value in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am trying to write a custom Angular validator for Kendo-UI datepicker component. I have written the validation function and hooked it up to the `kendo-datepicker` HTML component.

The issue is that if any fields are missing, the FormControl passed to the validator will have  `null` as its `value`. If `MM/dd/yyyy` are all there, it has the actual date object.

I would like my validator to error out if one or two `MM/dd/yyyy` components are missing, but not all three (ie when the user has cleared/not touched the component).

Comment: I guess it's not currently possible, feature request here: https://feedback.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/1360802-datepicker-validation-of-incomplete-input Please go comment on it!